# how can installs of xp from two different cds end up with same key?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, product-key

Im installing xp pro sp3 on a new hd, create new partition, totally fresh install. After install, I run cdkeyreader and write down the key. I then install to same hd using a different cd, but I select delete partition and start really fresh. After install is done, I run cdkeyreader and get the key from the previous cd!

My cds are original dell reinstall disks and both have coa stickers reporting two different keys.

How can this happen?

Answer (score -1):

That's because DELL are using OEM SLP keys, this is explained in more detail here:

https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-General-Wiki/Windows-7-SLP-Keys/ta-p/5190724

https://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/398475-dell-oem-license-reinstall-help-same-key-each.html

Hth.

Comment: Please include some context from the link in your post. Link-only answers are subject to removal as they can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: ...and what happens when I replace mobo and/or hard drives over the years with non-dell parts? any reason ms won't honor activation , even with my valid key stickers? thanks!

Comment: mobo might not work. Hard drive ought to.